# How to fetch rows from middle of the table in mysql using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to display rows from the database table on the UI. So, lets say we have 200 rows in the table. So , my first hit will give me first 20 rows. Now, i want to fetch next 20 rows in the next hit. I am using Hibernate for handling database CRUD operations.

query.setMaxResults(int size) works fine for first hit .But how to handle transactions for 2nd and onwards hits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- a particular page of the result set may be selected by calling setMaxResults(), setFirstResult().

see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html

Answer (score 1):

[setFirstResult(int firstResult)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult(int)) will set which row to start the fetch at. In your case...

```
query.setFirstResult(20);
```

...to make the query return results starting with the 21st result.

Comment: I am sorry...my question was very trivial...i googled but i could not any link ....thanks a lot for answering