# Retrieve database entries starting from a particular row

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows

Say I have 50 rows in my database table and I wanted to start retrieving database entries starting with row 9.

**How can I retrieve data from a database table starting at row 9?**

My code for pulling data from my db table:

```
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listheadlines ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OFFSET keyword like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listheadlines ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 9");
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter ( [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) ).

```
"SELECT * FROM listheadlines ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9, 18446744073709551615"
```

Or to get only 20 rows starting at offset 9:

```
"SELECT * FROM listheadlines ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9, 20"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listheadlines ORDER BY id Desc").setFirstResult(9);
```

Please check this once

[How to fetch rows from middle of the table in mysql using hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383580/how-to-fetch-rows-from-middle-of-the-table-in-mysql-using-hibernate)